# Keep ASP.NET ViewState without being passed via QueryString

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, query-string, viewstate

I have a form with its method being "get" that passes the variables and their values to the query string, respectively. However, it also passes the viewstate variable in the query string. Now, I have a very long viewstate value on the given page, and if passed in the query string, the viewstate variable will cause the page to error out, due to "too long of a query string" which happens to also be too long of a url.

I cannot merely remove the viewstate variable - I need it. But I need to pass the viewstate variable along via some method other than get when the form is submitted, while the other inputs of the form (the non-hidden inputs) are appended to the query string. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is in your viewstate that is making it so large? If you're serializing whole objects or lists of objects, try passing only the IDs of those objects instead of the fully serialized data. Yes, you'll need to hit the cache or the database again, but it also reduces the amount of data transferred to/from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the method to "post" and then use request.form to get your variables?

Otherwise, you might be able to use the session object...
...or a serializable class object
...or a temp table in a database

Several different options